# f# byte[] -> hex -> string conversion

Tags: f#

I have byte array as input. I would like to convert that array to string that contains hexadecimal representation of array values. This is F# code:

```
let ByteToHex bytes = 
    bytes 
    |> Array.map (fun (x : byte) -> String.Format("{0:X2}", x))

let ConcatArray stringArray = String.Join(null, (ByteToHex  stringArray))
```

This produces result I need, but I would like to make it more compact so that I have only one function.
I could not find function that would concat string representation of each byte at the end 
of ByteToHex. 
I tried Array.concat, concat_map, I tried with lists, but the best I could get is array or list of strings.

Questions:

1. What would be simplest, most elegant way to do this?
2. Is there string formatting construct in F# so that I can replace String.Format from System assembly?

Example input:  [|0x24uy; 0xA1uy; 0x00uy; 0x1Cuy|]  should produce string "24A1001C"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is nothing inherently wrong with your example.  If you'd like to get it down to a single expression then use the String.contcat method.

```
let ByteToHex bytes = 
    bytes 
    |> Array.map (fun (x : byte) -> System.String.Format("{0:X2}", x))
    |> String.concat System.String.Empty
```

Under the hood, String.concat will just call into String.Join.  Your code may have to be altered slighly though because based on your sample you import System.  This may create a name resolution conflict between F# String and System.String.

Comment: Perfect. I tried with String.Concat, but I didn't add "System.String.Empty" argument.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to transform and accumulate in one step, `fold` is your answer. `sprintf` is the F# string format function.

```
let ByteToHex (bytes:byte[]) =
    bytes |> Array.fold (fun state x-> state + sprintf "%02X" x) ""
```

This can also be done with a StringBuilder

```
open System.Text

let ByteToHex (bytes:byte[]) =
        (StringBuilder(), bytes)
        ||> Array.fold (fun state -> sprintf "%02X" >> state.Append)  
        |> string
```

produces:

```
[|0x24uy; 0xA1uy; 0x00uy; 0x1Cuy|] |> ByteToHex;;
val it : string = "24A1001C"
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another answer:

```
let hashFormat (h : byte[]) =
  let sb = StringBuilder(h.Length * 2)
  let rec hashFormat' = function
    | _ as currIndex when currIndex = h.Length -> sb.ToString()
    | _ as currIndex ->
      sb.AppendFormat("{0:X2}", h.[currIndex]) |> ignore
      hashFormat' (currIndex + 1)
  hashFormat' 0
```

The upside of this one is that it's tail-recursive and that it pre-allocates the exact amount of space in the string builder as will be required to convert the byte array to a hex-string.

For context, I have it in this module:

```
module EncodingUtils

open System
open System.Text
open System.Security.Cryptography
open Newtonsoft.Json

let private hmacmd5 = new HMACMD5()
let private encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
let private enc (str : string) = encoding.GetBytes str
let private json o = JsonConvert.SerializeObject o
let md5 a = a |> (json >> enc >> hmacmd5.ComputeHash >> hashFormat)
```

Meaning I can pass md5 any object and get back a JSON hash of it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another.  I'm learning F#, so feel free to correct me with more idiomatic ways of doing this:

```
let bytesToHexString (bytes : byte[]) : string =
    bytes
    |> Seq.map (fun c -> c.ToString("X2"))
    |> Seq.reduce (+)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks fine to me. Just to point out another, in my opinion, very helpful function in the Printf module, have a look at `ksprintf`. It passes the result of a formated string into a function of your choice (in this case, the identity function).

```
val ksprintf : (string -> 'd) -> StringFormat<'a,'d> -> 'a  
    sprintf, but call the given 'final' function to generate the result.
```

Answer (score -1):

To be honest, that doesn't look terrible (although I also have *very* little F# experience). Does F# offer an easy way to iterate (foreach)? If this was C#, I might use something like (where `raw` is a `byte[]` argument):

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (byte b in raw) {
            sb.Append(b.ToString("x2"));
        }
        return sb.ToString()
```

I wonder how that translates to F#...

Comment: Hehe, I can wite it that way in F#, but check this presentation by Luca Bolognese http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/TL11/
In first few minutes there is explanation about difference between imperative and declarative programming and example is about iterators.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll watch for a better answer, then. I could do to learn some F# ;-p